# process of executing fork ()

Tags: c, fork

I have executed the following code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello \t");
    fork();
    fork();

   return 0;
}
```

Output : `hello hello hello hello`

Does this mean that `fork()` create exact copy of the code for the child process as that of the parent process except the `fork()` call which gets executed is eliminated?

This is confusing me because I studied somewhere that "`fork()` begins execution from the next line of the code". So, if this is true then it should create 3 child processes and 1 parent process and should print `"hello"` only once.

Please resolve this .

I ran this code on gcc compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the string "hello" was stored in the output buffer of the parent process.

`printf` flushes the buffer when it meets `\n`, otherwise it prints the output string only if the buffer is full.

By default, the child process inherits the buffer of parent process, so if the buffer is not flushed, the buffer of child process also contains "hello".

if :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello \n");
    fork();
    fork();

   return 0;
}
```

You will see only one "hello".

Answer (score 1):

This is because of printf... u say use printf("hello \n") in order the buffer is flushed after a newline or u can use fflush(stdout) in u r code and the output will be just one hello...